# Not able to pass down an object to history.push()

Tags: javascript, json, chatkit

Basically, I have an object name as `currentUser` generated from chatkit server. This object contains all the information as well as some methods of currently logged in user.

I want to pass this object as a prop to another component. I tried passing it to `history.push` by initially `stringify`ing it, but after parsing the object at receiving end, I am not able to access the methods of the object. I know that `json.stringify` does exclude functions. Is there any other way that the `stringify` method does include the methods as well?

Can anyone suggest another way for passing down this object as props. I have seen something called `localStorage`. I am not sure how to use it. I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: It would help to show some basic code with what does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/your url',
  state: { anyKeyName: yourObject }
})
```